# Passing CoreData relationships down a view hierarchy

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying very hard to pass CoreData objects with strong one2many relationships down my view hierarchy.

Imagine a Todolist app:

1. Every List object has a one2many relationship with a Task object.
2. Every Task object has a one2many relationship with a SubTask object.

I query CoreData at the root with FetchedRequests to get the List object. I now iterate over the Task objects, and make a View for each of them. Then in each of those views I need to iterate over its SubTask objects. At each of these levels, edits can be made, and should be propogated back up.

I'm having a really hard time with code like this:

```swift
struct TaskListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    @Binding var taskData: TaskData

    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(self.taskList.tasks ?? [], id: \.id) { t in
                TaskRowView(taskData: $t)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives a lot of errors. Like:

1. If I change it to use indicies, it says has no attribute .indicies
2. Right now it says Generic struct ‘ForEach’ requires that ‘NSOrderedSet’ conform to ‘RandomAccessCollection’
3. Value of type ‘NSOrderedSet.Element’ (aka ‘Any’) has no member ‘id’

And a lot others to count.

Do you have a better method? Should I be doing queries from coredata at every step? I don’t really know why it’s so hard to migrate what I already had working with Bindings and a root level data structure to coredata.

I can’t seem to query just one item out of the database by UUID. I wish this was more like mongodb than sql.

Here is an example project I made to make the problem simple. I wonder if someone could have a look?

https://github.com/ryanpeach/MySwiftTaskList

These are the primary Views:

TaskList+Extensions

```
extension TaskList: Identifiable {

    var duration: Double {
        var out = 0.0
        for t in self.tasks ?? [] {
            out += (t as! Task).duration
        }
        return out
    }

    func getTasks() -> [Task] {
        var out: [Task] = []
        for t in self.tasks ?? [] {
            out.append(t as! Task)
        }
        return out
    }
}
```

ContentView (root)

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: TaskList.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(
                keyPath: \TaskList.name,
                ascending: true
            )
    ]) var taskListList: FetchedResults<TaskList>

    @State private var taskListName: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    TextField("TaskList Name", text: $taskListName)
                    Button(action: {
                        self.addTaskList()
                    }){
                        Text("Create Task List")
                    }
                }
                List{
                    ForEach(self.taskListList, id: \.name) { tl in
                        NavigationLink(destination: TaskListView(taskList: tl)) {
                            Text(tl.name)
                            Text(String(tl.duration))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func addTaskList() {
        let newTask = TaskList(context: managedObjectContext)
        // newTask.id = UUID()
        newTask.name = taskListName

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

TaskListView

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct TaskListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State private var taskName: String = ""

    /* Option1: Does not work
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Task>
    var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>

    @State private var _taskList: TaskList?

    init(taskList: TaskList) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Task>(
            entity: Task.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [
                NSSortDescriptor(
                    keyPath: \Task.order,
                    ascending: true
                )
            ],
            predicate: NSPredicate(format: "taskList = %@", taskList)
        )
        _taskList = taskList
        tasks = fetchRequest.wrappedValue
    }
    */

    @Binding var taskList: TaskList

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
                TextField("Task Name", text: $taskName)
                Button(action: {
                    self.addTask()
                }){
                    Text("Create Task")
                }
            }
            List{
                ForEach(self.taskList.getTasks(), id: \.order) { <------- The errors happen here
                    t in
                    HStack{
                        Text(t.name)
                        Text(String(t.duration))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func addTask() {
        let newTask = Task(context: managedObjectContext)
        // newTask.id = UUID()
        newTask.name = taskName
        taskList.addToTasks(newTask)

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct TaskListView_Previewer: View {
    @State var taskList: TaskList
    var body: some View {
        TaskListView(
            taskList: $taskList
        )
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate a learning experience from all of this. Just not really sure how I'm "supposed" to be handling my data with CoreData. I had examples working from a static data source kinda like json and it worked flawlessly, so I guess I just don't understand the restrictions of this data type.

Answer (score 0):

A user on Discord mentioned to me that I should use @ObservedObject instead of @Binding for CoreData objects and it works fantastic. It was really that simple.